# Show nav once the nav has been hidden

Tags: css, media-queries

I've got some CSS and media queries which hide and show my navigation:

So by default the navigation is:

```
nav {
  display: inline;
}
```

Then using media query I hide it:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

All works perfectly well, I then have some JavaScript hooked up to a button to show and hide the navigation when the media query is in effect.

However when I resize the browser back to full screen, larger than 767px the navigation does not reappear. How can I get the navigation to appear for desktop users?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make the js add a class to the nav and use !important to overwrite the media query statement...

```
nav {
  display: inline;
}
.force_display{
    display:inline !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

just add force_display class in the js function (assuming you're using jquery)...

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('force_display');
});
```

Comment: The button is to toggle the display of the menu when at small resolutions, hence I hide the nav menu at low resolutions and use a button to display. What I need is the ability to unhide the nav when at larger resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

bind the jquery resize handler to the window like this

```
$(window).resize(function(e){
    if($(window).width() > 767){
        $('nav').show()
    } else {
        $('nav').hide()
    }
})
```

there is probably a few optimisations you can do with caching objects but this should get you want you need to start with

Answer (score 0):

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    nav
    {
        display: inline!important;
    }
}
```

Kai Qing's answer helped me realise that I just needed to override the inline CSS the jQuery .toggle event was adding - Inside the correct media query of course.